# how to make django module fully independent?

Tags: python, django, model

Look at my model class

```
from django.db import models
from meeting.models import Meeting

# Create your models here.


class Agenda(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
```

Here Agenda, class needs Meeting class for foreign key. Is it possible to do something where the Agenda class will work if importing Meeting class is fail. If the meeting class is not found it will create a default meeting object.

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking, as that kind of check can only really occur once (on syncdb or migration). How will this app be managed? Can you handle a migration if a user decides to add the `meeting` module?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this conditionally, but with heavy caveats that it could break and probably break between server restarts.

```
from django.db import models
try:
    from meeting.models import Meeting
    has_meetings = True
except:
    has_meetings = False

# Create your models here.


class Agenda(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    if has_meetings:
        meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
```